# correct way to point static URL to CDN in Django?

Tags: django

I assumed this works:

```
if DEBUG:
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
else:
  STATIC_URL = 'https://absolutepath.com/ab3bf/static/'
```

And yes, templates for `{% static 'path/file' %}` to `https://absolutepath.com/ab3bf/static/path/file` correctly.

Is this **the correct way** to point to a CDN URL? My Google-fu fails here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is absolutely right. There is no expectation that `STATIC_URL` necessarily points to a local URL.

No doubt you already have your [`STATICFILES_STORAGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-from-a-cloud-service-or-cdn) set up to deploy your files to the CDN when you run `collectstatic`.